# Injecting dependencies to an Automapper TypeConverter in ASP.NET Core

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, automapper

To get a DI framework to inject dependencies into an Automapper custom TypeConverter, you normally use the `ConstructServicesUsing` method of the `MapperConfiguration` object. So with ASP.NET Core DI, I expect to be able to configure AutoMapper like this:

```
public static IMapperConfiguration Configure(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
         cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>();
         cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => provider.GetService(type));
    });
    config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    return config;
}
```

The `MapperConfiguration` object would be configured as an injectable service in startup.cs thus:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //other service configuration omitted for simplicity

    //Automapper config
    var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    var config = AutoMapperConfig.Configure(provider);
    services.AddInstance(config);
}
```

And the dependency (in this case Automapper itself) would be injected into the TypeConverter constructor like this.

```
public class MyConverter : ITypeConverter<ThisType, ThatType>
{
    private IMapper _mapper;

    public MyConverter(IMapperConfiguration mapperConfig)
    {
        var mc = mapperConfig as MapperConfiguration;
        _mapper = mc.CreateMapper();
    }

    public ThatType Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        //do something with _mapper here
    }
}
```

I have used this pattern successfully with several DI frameworks, but I can't get it to work with ASP.NET Core. At a guess, I think it might be that Automapper needs to be given the real IServiceProvider instance that is built by .NET after the ConfigureServices method has completed. However, even when I postpone that part of the configuration until the Configure method (see below), the dependency still doesn't get injected into the TypeConverter.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider provider)
{
    var config = provider.GetService<IMapperConfiguration>();
    config.ConstructServicesUsing(type => provider.GetService(type));
}
```

So my question is: how do I configure Automapper with ASP.NET Core so that it injects dependencies into custom TypeConverters?

Comment: Are you still working with ASP.NET 5 beta7 or beta8? I remember `services.AddInstance` to have been renamed to `AddSingleton` to keep it in line with other singleton registrations

Comment: My bad, it was in the announcement for RC2, but it was so long ago that I thought it was before RC1's release. https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/119

Comment: I'm using RC1 in any case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem lies in the correct configuration of the `ConstructServicesUsing` factory method. As @Tseng pointed out, using the `IServiceCollection.AddSingleton` method allows Automapper to be configured in the `ConfigureServices` method of Startup.cs, which is where it should be done:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //other service configuration omitted for simplicity

    //Automapper config
    services.AddSingleton(provider => AutoMapperConfig.Configure(provider));
}
```

But crucially, Automapper must be configured to use .NET Core's `ActivatorUtilities` class to create service instances (credit to [this article](http://derpturkey.com/vnext-dependency-injection-overview/) for giving me the idea):

```
public static IMapperConfiguration Configure(IServiceProvider provider)
{
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
         cfg.AddProfile<MyProfile>();
         cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(provider, type));
    });
    config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    return config;
}
```

With this approach, Automapper is configured to inject any service dependencies into custom `TypeConverters` and `ValueResolvers`. Just make sure that any such services are also added to the `IServiceCollection` instance in `ConfigureServices`.

Answer (score 2):

You can/should use a factory method to inject/instantiate the service.

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IMapperConfiguration>( (serviceProvider) => AutoMapperConfig.Configure(serviceProvider) );
```

This way you delay the call to `Configure` until the first time `IMapperConfiguration` is being resolved. Since it's singleton, it will stay alive for the rest of your application container and further calls to `RequestService` will return the same instance.

**Edit:**

Try removing the `config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` from your `AutoMapperConfig.Configure` method and add the following code in `Startup.cs`

```cs
public void Configure(IServiceProvider app) 
{
    app.VerifyAutoMapperConfig();
}
```

AutoMapperConfigExtensions.cs

```cs
// So one doesn't have to add namespaces to become available 
// inside Startup.cs; Recommended way all middleware register their
// AddXxx and UseXxx extension methods
namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection {
    public static class AutoMapperConfigExtensions
    {
        public static void VerifyAutoMapperConfig(this IServiceProvider app) 
        {
            var config = app.RequestService<IMapperConfiguration>();
            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looked really promising. Unfortunately however, I get the same error when attempting to use the TypeConverter: `MyConverter needs to have a constructor with 0 args or only optional args\r\nParameter name: type`. I wonder if AM 4.2 is using the IServiceProvider reference to inject dependencies in the same that it used to in previous releases.

Comment: I suspect you have a circular dependency here. Your `MyConverter` has a dependency on `IMapperConfiguration`, but `IMapperConfiguration` can only be resolved after the call to `AutoMapperConfig.Configure`, but since you're calling `config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` inside of configure it tries to resolve it before it returns. Try to move this call outside of the Configure method, i.e. inside Startup.cs's `Configure(IServiceProvider app)` method. I'll update the answer with an example

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't fix it either. Btw, when I debug the code, I can see that the AutomapperConfig.Configure method is called directly from the service configuration is added in Startup.cs. It is not deferred until first use as you mention. That makes me wonder if I have done something wrong, somewhere.

Comment: Also, I tried replacing `MyConverter`'s `IMapperConfiguration` dependency with another injectable service, but got the same error, so I think that rules out a circular dependency issue.

Comment: Is `provider.GetService(type)` in  being called in `cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(type => provider.GetService(type));`? If not it may be using the wrong instance of `IMapperConfiguration` not the one you configured. You aren't using the static instances of it right?

Comment: No, I'm using the recommended AM 4.2 approach. I have just found out the problem however. I'll add a write up shortly for other people's benefit.