# automapper - inject dependency in resolver

Tags: c#, automapper

One of my fields needs a mapping from a database call hence I am using a resolver that takes a Repository instance to make a database call and return the result.

I am using a Lazy static auto mapper instance for mapping. I am not sure how to inject repository dependency in the resolver. Any idea?

> Error: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot dynamically create an
> instance of type '*.MyCustomResolver'. Reason: No parameterless
> constructor defined.

Code:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Order, OrderDTO>()            
            .ForMember(dest => dest.StateId, 
                 opt => opt.MapFrom<MyCustomResolver, string>(src => src.StateText));
    }
}

public class WebAppMapping
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IMapper> Lazy = new Lazy<IMapper>(() =>
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {            
            cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>();
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return mapper;
    });
    public static IMapper Mapper => Lazy.Value;
}

public class MyCustomResolver : IMemberValueResolver<object, object, string, int>
{        
    private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepo;
    public MyCustomResolver(IOrderRepository orderRepo)
    {
        _orderRepo = orderRepo;
    }

    public int Resolve(object source, object destination, string sourceMember, int destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        //call _orderRepo.GetId Method        
    }
}

//I am using my mapper like following
var output = WebAppMapping.Mapper.Map<OrderDTO>(order);


//My repository instance is already registered with DI
builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();

I tried doing this but same error
//Program.cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<MyCustomResolver>();
```

Comment: Oh Yes! Fixed now!

Comment: Does it work with `ConstructServicesUsing()`? See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#low-level-api-s

Comment: I saw a few examples with `ConstructServicesUsing`  but they require it to be configured with `IServiceProvider` instance. I don't have that either in my case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37296905

Comment: Can't you use `BuildServiceProvider()` to build the service provider? What else do you have to resolve types to instances?